# How do I log particular events from Rails to a log file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

### Requirements

I would like to keep an audit log of particular events, such as:

- User logged in successfully
- User could not log in (with reason: wrong password, unconfirmed, etc.)
- SuperUser modified another users details (with what they changed)
- etc.

This log should include details such as:

- The logged in user performing the action (based on the controller's `current_user`)
- The record being modified (such as the other user record in the case of super users)
- The IP address of request for that action

This log should also be stored in a file on the filesystem, not a database table so it can be ingested by another service on the machine at a later time.

### Some possibilities

Here is a short list of the approaches I have considered so far:

#### ActiveRecord::Observer

Observers give a nice separated way of watching for these particular events.
I could then get the observer to append to a log file, but I'm not sure how easy I would be able to obtain the result of such a call (such as login failed or worked) and I would need to somehow call the controller method `current_user` to find out the logged in user and get the HTTP request to obtain the IP address.

#### An auditing gem (such as audited, auditable, paper_trail, etc.)

These gems have the convenience of knowing how to get access to the controller for the current user and IP address, but they all log to an audit table in the database. `Auditable` is particularly nice because it can audit any method call on an object, not just an AR callback, but I may need to patch it to write to a file instead of the database.. or something?

#### ActiveSupport::Notifications

I still need to read up on this, but I believe it offers low-level a way of subscribing to low-level events within rails. This might be too low-level for this situation, but I need to investigate further.

#### Log4r

It seems this will make a nice log file, but I don't think it has any way of watching for events. This would only be part of the problem.

### Any advice?

Is there a best practices way of doing this? Can you recommend any gems or lessons learned from previous experience? Anything else I should consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for the responses.
Casper, I did decide to build something custom.

I see your point with writing to a local db anyway, but the requirement for this project is to dump log files so a more elaborate log parsing service can interrogate the files and even combine them with information from other sources.

In order to get logging from both models and controllers, I ended up making a module that I would include in both the observers and `ApplicationController`.

The module looks a little something like this:

```
module MyEventLogger
  mattr_accessor :logged_current_user
  mattr_accessor :logged_remote_ip

  def log_event(message)
    @@logger ||= Logger.new(Rails.root.join('log', 'audit.log'))
    @@logger.info "#{Time.now} | #{logged_current_user}@#{logged_remote_ip} | #{message}"
  end

  def logged_current_user
    @@logged_current_user || "SYSTEM"
  end

  def logged_remote_ip
    @@logged_remote_ip || "NO IP ADDRESS"
  end
end
```

ApplicationController would have:

```
include MyEventLogger
before_filter :setup_logger

...

def setup_logger
  MyEventLogger.logged_current_user = current_user
  MyEventLogger.logged_ip_address = request.remote_ip
end
```

The observer would just have to `include MyEventLogger` and it would have access to the `log_event` method and the current user and ip address. For example:

```
class UserObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  include MyEventLogger

  def after_save(user)
    log_event "The User #{user} was saved by #{logged_current_user}"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts:

The auditing gems sound closest to what you want. If you look at their source code they are not that complex, and most seem to actually be built around Rails Observers. You could easily use their code as a base to create your own specialized versions.

If you look at he code of Audited for example you will see it's actually quite simple to store the `current_user` (if you decide to roll your own implementation):

https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited/blob/master/lib/audited/sweeper.rb

I don't think having the auditing data in a DB is necessarily bad. You might actually find that useful one day when you need to track down some complex problem from thousands of previous transactions. You can always create a simple Rake task to dump the data into a logfile format when needed.

However I will say that `Log4r` is quite nice, and I've used it myself in a couple of projects. But I did not have an audit-type need. Only basic logging for debugging and troubleshooting.

You COULD also consider combining something like your own Observer-type system with a Log4r driver instead of a DB driver, if that's what you want. Because it does sound a little bit like you might need to trigger logging events outside of what the Observer system provides anyway. Which means you're going to have to either implement extensions to existing gems, or use a gem as a base and extend it with your own functionality.

Anyway - I still see the DB approach as actually a benefit, and kind of cool to be able to run queries on your audit-trail. Stuff like that can't hurt (Log4r btw. supports custom "output drivers" also, so even that could be used to log into a DB).

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing my personal experience with this:

I created something very similar to what you mention here. I used a table in the database, trapped the relevant `post` request in the application_controller, and passed the info to the model associated with my log table. The logic was quite trivial, and I had all the control I wanted. The only effort was in selecting/ rejecting particular transactions, and restructuring all useful params to fit nicely in a text field.

If you decide to take that route, I will be happy to share more details.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that, is wherever you want to run a logged action, run it in a block

I really recommend looking at Chapter 18 of Eloquent Ruby by Russ Olsen http://books.google.com/books?id=-s2xL0pVsLUC&lpg=PA219&ots=l7I3oAK3M2&dq=eloquent%20ruby%20chapter%2018&pg=PA219#v=onepage&q&f=false and maybe 'Using Blocks' in Chapter 2 of Gregory Brown's Ruby Best Practices http://majesticseacreature.com/rbp-book/pdfs/rbp_1-0.pdf

e.g.

```
def with_logging(description)
 begin
    @logger.debug( "Starting #{description}" ) 
    yield # this is when the code in the block executes
    @logger.debug( "Completed #{description}" )
  rescue
    @logger.error( "#{description} failed!!") 
    raise
  end
end

with_logging('code example') { puts "just printing something" }
```

Also: It might be worth looking into tools like graylog http://graylog2.org/about/gelf (and see http://arrrrcamp.be/videos/2011/lennart-koopmann---managing-the-logs-of-your-rails-applications/ ) or these posts http://openmymind.net/2012/4/4/You-Really-Should-Log-Client-Side-Error/ (javascript), https://github.com/TwP/logging , http://amon.cx/